# App crashes when run unittest due to 'objc_getClassList returned more classes than it should have.'

Tags: iphone, ios

I've struggled with this error hours, and finally I drill down to this piece of code. This code works well when you "Run" the app, but will cause app crashes when "Test". I've googled and found this question:

[Occasional errors when running OCUnit application test suite on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668894/occasional-errors-when-running-ocunit-application-test-suite-on-device)

But the solution doesn't work for me ;-(

I am a newbie iOS developer, so I'm not sure if this piece of code does something evil. Can anybody tell me:

1. Is it OK to do the job like in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method?
2. Why does this piece code throw the error?

Thanks!

```
#import "BRAppDelegate.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@implementation BRAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
        [lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

            }];
        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error){

        }];

    });
    return YES;
}
```

### EDIT

The strangest thing is that if I comment out

```
[group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

}];
```

No crash occurs!

Answer (score 1):

ALAssetLibrary isn't safe to run on any thread but the main thread. You use GCDD todispatch it to the background and therefore run in another thread.

read: http://death-mountain.com/2011/05/alassetslibrary-and-threads/

also take race to avoid mutating the asset library while enumerating it. that'd be bad too: [Has anyone experienced crashes when using ALAssetsLibrary in a background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480611/has-anyone-experienced-crashes-when-using-alassetslibrary-in-a-background-thread)

---

### BUT the main problem is how you use the lib I think...

you allocate it in a block.. a new one: but in a block  so it goes away after the block is done because nobody else is holding on to it.

move the allocation of `lib` into the main thread and save it as a member variable in the app delegate

so:

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
    ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
```

becomes:

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
     ALAssetsLibrary *_lib;
}

...

// Override point for customization after application launch.
_lib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];          
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by clearing Xcode’s cache by deleting my `DerivedData` folder.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Comment: A little less nuclear: open the Organizer, choose __Projects__ at the top, select your project on the left, and click __Delete…__ under __Derived Data__ on the right.