# KIF in a project with a static library

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing, sentestingkit, kif-framework

I am planning to use KIF in the following setup:
1. My own static library
2. Many 'shell' apps that use the static library. These apps provide the content and configuration, but they all use the common library to load the content based not the configuration.

How should I approach integrating KIF? Should I add KIF to the shell apps?
The user interacts with the pages/content through the library.
For example the static library has a web view that displays the content. The accessibilityLabels will be set in the library.

Thanks for any insight.

UPDATE:
find KIF at https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF ("KIF, which stands for Keep It Functional, is an iOS integration test framework. It allows for easy automation of iOS apps by leveraging the accessibility attributes that the OS makes available for those with visual disabilities.")

Comment: Suggestion: When you use a third party library, include a brief description of what it is and what it does, as well as a link to the source. The tech universe is big and diverse. I had never heard of KIF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works fine. The only problem I run into was Google Analytics.
see [Occasional errors when running OCUnit application test suite on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668894/occasional-errors-when-running-ocunit-application-test-suite-on-device/21136665#21136665)

so KIF was run in the shell apps, not the library.
accessibility labels set in the library are easily accessible.